# What can be done to prevent CVE-2016-6662?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

This assumes `mysqld_safe` script that starts the MySQL

```
root     14967  0.0  0.1   4340  1588 ?        S    06:41   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe

mysql    15314  1.2  4.7 558160 47736 ?        Sl   06:41   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
```

two processes where first can be modified based on `my.cnf` 
as explained in the document.

```
--malloc-lib=LIB
```

http://legalhackers.com/advisories/MySQL-Exploit-Remote-Root-Code-Execution-Privesc-CVE-2016-6662.html

Comment: thank you for providing on hold for this question, i will be cynic and express that certainly you are helping the community that way. what ever the reason to do so, i would ask you proactively to comment if possible the reason so i can improve the question.